# Is eventfd_write thread safe?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

If we have multiple writes. As an event id, writing thread safety is really useful. Document does not say anything about thread safety.

```
Additional glibc features
       The GNU C library defines an additional type, and two functions that attempt  to  abstract
       some of the details of reading and writing on an eventfd file descriptor:

       typedef uint64_t eventfd_t;

       int eventfd_read(int fd, eventfd_t *value);
       int eventfd_write(int fd, eventfd_t value);

       The functions perform the read and write operations on an eventfd file descriptor, return-
       ing 0 if the correct number of bytes was transferred, or -1 otherwise.
```

Comment: I'm just going [by this man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) and would simply use `write(2)`, which seems perfectly safe. The whole point of an eventfd is that you can use it for synchronization, and the Posix I/O primitives (`read`, `write`) are thread-safe and atomic with respect to the transfered data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing to an eventfd is thread safe, i.e., two threads (or even processes) are allowed to write to the same fd at the same time, and they will be properly serialized.

The eventfd's internal counter is guaranteed to have been increased when `write()`/`eventfd_write()` returns, but when two calls happen at the same time, there can be no gurantee about their order.
A third thread that monitors the eventfd by reading it might see one or the other increment first (or it might not be fast enough and see only the sum after both increments).

When you are calling `write(fd, &value, 8)`, and another thread modifies the `value` variable at the same time, you cannot predict whether the increment will use the old or the new value (or a combination of both, if the modification isn't atomic). However, the actual value read from that memory and used for the increment will be consistent.

Comment: Can you please share the source you're based on? is it the source code itself? Why do you exaggerate way saying "or even processes" ? Isn't it the opposite? Two processes don't share the same `fd`, so it's like a `pipe`, but two threads share the same `fd`

Comment: Ok, I found it in the `ATTRIBUTES` section in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html.