# How to write function<void()> to pipe/socketpair?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, pipe

There is a need to send std::function to thread inside pipe/socket. Writing to socket is important because I am using pollfd to check if something was written to call queue. For now I am using std::queue but it cannot notify my main thread that something was written. Is there a way to trigger pollfd using std::queue? Or is there a way to write std::function to socket/pipe?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a file descriptor purely for notifications. Linux has just the thing: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html

Comment: You mean writing whatever the function returns when called to a socket?

Comment: No. I have an application which runs it's own loop. I can insert calls in this loop using poll callback. I need to send function<void()> to this thread using fd to trigger function running my function<void()> tasks.

Comment: Not really clear what you actually try to do. Can you provide some code example, and at very least the function signatures of the API you are using?

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to write then? A function address? That makes very little sense.

Comment: Header: https://github.com/twaik/termux-x11/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/lorie/include/lorie-message-queue.hpp  . Source: https://github.com/twaik/termux-x11/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/lorie/message-queue.cpp . Usage: https://github.com/twaik/termux-x11/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/lorie/include/lorie-compositor.hpp#L42 . Adding fd to pollfd: https://github.com/twaik/termux-x11/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/lorie/compositor.cpp#L49 .

Comment: Botje is correct. Use that sort of mechanism to notify your other threads of "things waiting to happen". You don't "use std::queue" or "write std::function" - those are the things that then get examined once the notification has been observed.

Comment: We don't want to examine your whole real project. Present a [mcve].

Comment: The main idea is to redirect function calls to the main loop.

Comment: Creating minimal reproducible example will be a bit complicated, because it uses libwayland.

Comment: Which is exactly why that's your job not ours :) You should abstract libwayland out of the problem as your first step probably.

Comment: I use std::function<void()> to store std::bind(&func, args...). Everything I need it to send this function<void()> to my main thread.

Comment: No, you don't. That's what you think the solution is, not what you want to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going at it slightly backwards.

You don't "send" a queue or a function to a thread. You inform the thread that there is some work to be done; the code running on that thread then proceeds to examine some shared thing (your queue) and pulls out anything it needs to work with (newly-pushed function objects, for example) after performing the appropriate synchronisation tasks (mutex!).

If you're already using sockets (and you're on a compatible platform), [eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) is perfect for this task, as it gives you an FD that you can watch for in your existing `select`/`poll`/`epoll` loop; then you just trigger that whenever you like from the thread that wants to create the notification.

Otherwise, condition variables are great for signalling across threads.

---

#### Main thread

- Poll for activity on FDs
- When activity found on an FD:

  - Is it my "queue has new functions" event FD?

    - Lock the queue
    - Pop the new function
    - Unlock the queue
    - Invoke the function (or whatever you need to do)

#### Provider thread

- Lock the queue
- Push the new function
- Unlock the queue
- Trigger the "queue has new functions" event FD?

---

Technically, you could serialise a pointer to your function object, and send the resulting bytes across an honest-to-god socket (within the same program only!) then reinterpret the bytes on receipt into a pointer, dereference the pointer, call the function.

But that's going to be a *real* mess, and causes complexities for lifetime management, and is just not how things are done.

Comment: Does eventfd need to be wrapped to mutex lock/unlock?

Comment: @TwaikYont I will leave researching the usage of eventfd as an exercise to the reader. Here's something to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24159633/560648

Comment: For what it's worth, this is exactly how I implemented my framework's message-passing and timer mechanisms, and it works great right alongside I/O handling.